# Subobject, contained object, member object: Difference?

Tags: c++

It has been almost 2 decades since I coded in C++, and it seems to me that the terminology has changed.  I've been web searching to see if there is actually any difference in the meaning of the three terms in the subject line, but haven't found any.  Neither, however, have I found the corroboration that they mean the same thing.

If I recall correctly, we used "member object" to refer to a property regardless of whether it is declared in a base class or a derived class.  These days, it seems that people also call this a "contained object", and a "subobject".  Are they in fact equivalent terms?

The most relevant thread that I could find is [Difference between sub-object and contained object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11427439/difference-between-sub-object-and-contained-object).  However, it discusses the derivation of objects, which I'm still not clear about.  Classes are derived, while objects are instantiated.  Some further search suggests that this is short hand for instantiating a derived class, but I'm foggy enough on the thread that I don't think it clearly answers the question posed here.  It could do with a more direct answer.

Thanks.

Comment: i might be mistaken, but I think all the terms you ask for don't have a strict definition and are used colloquially to mean whatever they are used for. With one exception: member object is quite unambiguously refering to a member object. Also "property" is not a c++ term.

Comment: I sort of suspected what you say about colloquiality  But even in their colloquiality, do the terms other than "member object" distinguish between whether they are declared in the base class or the derived class?  For that matter, does even the term "member object" refer to both?  For that matter, Does "base class" refer to just the parent class, or all ancestor classes?  Based on my readings of the diamond problem of multiple inheritance, I suspect the latter.  If you are able to respond to these, feel free to post it as an answer rather than a comment.  Thanks!

Comment: I agree with idclev.  Those are some vague terms.  If you are contrasting a "sub-object" with a "contained object" it sounds like you are talking about "inheritance" vs "containment".  (or "inheritance" vs "aggregation") I think you might get a clearer distinction searching on those terms.

Comment: I'm pretty confident that I appreciate the difference between inheritance and aggregation, but it seems that I automatically get a sort of aggregation by inheriting the member objects of a base class.  I'm more focused on the boundaries of the meaning of the more colloquial terms other than "member object" (actually, even "member object"). They all seem to apply to the usage `MyObject.SomeMemberObject`, regardless of whether the member object is declared in the base class or the derived class.

Comment: it would be rather confusing to distinguish between inherited and non inherited for the term "member" if you want to distinguish call it "non-inherited member" and "inherited member". A member is a member. And same for distinguishing between direct base class and non-indirect base class. A base class is a base class. If you want to distinguish call them "direct base class" and "non-direct base class" ;) I mean as long as you know what it means there is no problem, but same terms can be used differently in different context.

Comment: In some sense, you've answered certain aspects of the question. If I understood correctly, "member' could refer to an object declared in a base class or in a derived class.  "Base" could refer to immediate parent or an ancestor.  It doesn't speak to such clarifying nuance for the colloquial terms, but it does for the official terms.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments, all three terms seem to refer to the same thing, with "member object" being the formal term.  There seems to be no distinction between whether the member object is declared in the base class or the derived class.  Furthermore, "base class" refers to any ancestor class, while "derived" class refers to any descendant class.